# How to sort a CArray of pointers?

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

As you might have already guessed I don't want to sort the pointer addresses but the objects/data.

At the moment I have an array like this:

```
CArray <ReadObject *> readCollecion;
```

and I sort it like that:

```
std::sort(readCollecion.GetData(), readCollecion.GetData()+readCollecion.GetSize(), keySortFunction);
```

Works perfectly with the keySortFunction.

The problem is I need pointers to my objects because I need to modify the objects while they are already in the array. I guess I need and Array like this:

```
CArray <ReadObject *> readCollecion;
```

Now I can change the objects afterwards but my sort seems to be unable to deal with this.

Comment: Your original object should probably be `CArray < ReadObject > readCollection`

Comment: So I take it that you are changing the objects you're pointing to in such a way as to change the sort order? That is, are you changing the members used to determine sort order?

Comment: Assuming you're going to use ReadObject *, maybe you shouyld change the keySortFunction ?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, all you need to do is change the parameter type of `keySortFunction` from `const ReadObject&` to `const ReadObject*` and make the appropriate changes to the function to use `->` instead of `.`

Answer (score 0):

```
bool keySortFunction(const ReadObject& o1, const ReadObject& o2)
{
    return ...;
}

CArray <ReadObject> readCollecion; 
std::sort(readCollecion.GetData(), readCollecion.GetData()+readCollecion.GetSize(), eySortFunction);

...

CArray <ReadObject*> readCollecion2;
std::sort(readCollecion2.GetData(), readCollecion2.GetData()+readCollecion2.GetSize(), [](ReadObject* o1, ReadObject* o2)
{
    return keySortFunction(*o1, *o2);
});
```